# How to add meta tags correctly in next js Head component?

Tags: next.js, meta-tags, open-graph-beta

The meta tags inside my Head component are not recognized by LinkedIn inspector but when I check the html all tags are where they are expected to be.

Can someone explain how it works, please?

```
<Head>
    <title>Full Stack Developer</title>
    <meta
            name="description"
            property="og:description"
            content="Generated by create next app"
    />
    <meta name="title" property="og:title" content="Full Stack Developer" />
    <meta
            name="image"
            property="og:image"
            content="some links"
    />
    <meta name="author" content="Me" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
</Head>
```

[image: dev tools]